# HTMLPurifier dies when the following code is run through it

Tags: php, html, escaping, htmlpurifier

Using the latest release of HTMLPurifier with default configs.

The following code will cause the oh-so-lovely blank white page in PHP. Am I missing something? Even if I set HTML.TidyLevel to `light` or `none` it still breaks. Here is a partial log of the errors thrown when trying to purify the code below: http://pastie.org/private/13f0htscq0v8bhhlt7dpg

For reference, here is the associated code I'm using to do it:

```
$config = new HTMLPurifier_Config(new HTMLPurifier_ConfigSchema());
$config->set('HTML.TidyLevel', 'light'); // breaks with any level, even 'none'
self::$pure = new HTMLPurifier($config);
self::$pure->purify($str); // $str contains the code below
```

And, finally, the offending code:

```
<code>
<style type="text/css">
.block {
    position: relative;
}

.block h2 a span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 1px dashed #000;
}
</style>

<div class="block">
<h2><a href="#"><span></span>Title of block</a></h2>
<p>This entire block is clickable</p>
<ul>
    <li>Use</li>
    <li>Any</li>
    <li>Markup you like</li>
</ul>
<div>Even more divs!</div>
<p>without worrying about whether the element is allowed to be a child of an anchor</p>
</div>
</code>
```

Comment: Blank white page: a fatal error in you error logs perhaps?

Comment: Yes: http://pastie.org/private/13f0htscq0v8bhhlt7dpg

What is strange to me is it *seems* to be related to the above code. 99% of the time, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your htmlpurifier directory and install a fresh copy from the tarball.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config = new HTMLPurifier_Config(new HTMLPurifier_ConfigSchema());
$config->set('HTML.TidyLevel', 'light'); // breaks with any level, even 'none'
self::$pure = new HTMLPurifier($config);
self::$pure->purify($str); // $str contains the code below
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.