# htmlpurifier, overpurification of third party source

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

UPDATE 2: http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,5088,5113 Author has already identified the problem.

UPDATE: Issue appears to be exclusive to version 4.2.0. I have downgraded to 4.1.0 and it works. Thank you for all your help. Author of package notified.

I am scraping some pages like:

http://form.horseracing.betfair.com/horse-racing/010108/Catterick_Bridge-GB-Cat/1215

According to W3C validation it is valid XHTML Strict.

I am then using http://htmlpurifier.org/ to purify the HTML before loading into a DOMDocument. However it is only returning a single line of content.

Output:

```
12:15 Catterick Bridge - Tuesday 1st January 2008 - Timeform | Betfair
```

Code:

```
echo $content; # all good
$purifier = new \HTMLPurifier();
$content = $purifier->purify($content);
echo $content; # all bad
```

BTW it works for data sourced from another site, just as you say leaves the title for all pages from this domain.

Related Links

- [HTMLPurifier dies when the following code is run through it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291933/htmlpurifier-dies-when-the-following-code-is-run-through-it) (unanswered question on similar topic)

Comment: Make sure you don't reveal to us *which* line! It would take away all the fun of guessing.

Comment: Strange, that seems to be the title. Can you show the code you are using? (The purifier call and settings)

Comment: @Pekka, done, standard call, working fine for other content, just not any from this domain.

Comment: Hmm, if I copy and paste the HTML into their online demo form, I get exactly the same result.  How fun.

Comment: @esryl - just upgrade your HTML purifier?

Comment: @ajreal running latest version. tried full and standalone, both same results.

Comment: @esryl - is fine on my end (v4.1.0), what I did is `wget` the URL you provided and run locally. So, does the data pulling part if diff from you?

Comment: Why are you running HTML Purifier on the content before loading it into DOMDocument? That doesn't make very much sense to me.

Comment: @Edward Z. Yang I like the simplified HTML it returns me, much easier to query. Mind you, it just OCD running this particular source through. Maybe your right and I should just leave it alone :)

Comment: @ajreal will try 4.1.0, i am running 4.2.0, just need to find an old version.

Comment: ajreal: If this is indeed a regression from 4.1.0 to 4.2.0 that's useful information.

Comment: @Edward Z. Yang: found 4.1.0 on github and the problem is exclusive to the latest version. 4.1.0 is working perfectly. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need the HTML purifier. The DOMDocument class will take care of everything for you. However, it will trigger a warning on invalid html, so just do this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($content);
```

Then the error will not be triggered, and you can do what you wish with the HTML.

If you are scraping links, I would recommend that you use SimpleXMLElement::xpath(); That is much easier than working with the DOMDocument. Another example on that:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
$result = $xml->xpath('a/@href');

print_r($result);
```

You can get much more complex xpaths that allow you to specifiy class names, ids, and other attributes. This is much more powerful than DOMDocument.

Comment: yeah ocd was having me purify anything third party :) i am now just using pure domdocument and domxpath - which is perfect for my needs. in fact a bug in my own code led me to purification before loading into dom (that is since solved, and as such so is my need to purify).